# C# Mongo RunCommandAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is it possible to run

```
db.Users.createIndex({"FirstName" : 1, "LastName": 1});
```

from the RunCommandAsync also are there examples of what can be done from the command.

As a test I tried to run this but it through an exception

```
var indexCommand = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument{
        {"getIndexes", "Users"}
});
var results = await database.RunCommandAsync(indexCommand);
```

I know I can get and create indexes from the C# drivers, however I would like to keep a script in sync between those that want to build the indexes through C# and those that want to handle it directly on the DB.

Comment: Are you working with the new MongoDB driver?

Comment: I also have an exception with RunCommandAsync. Do you have any working examples with RunCommandAsync?

Comment: I have not found a way yet to do this.  At the moment I just wrote a script that I run from the shell

Comment: Maybe it would improve your question if you add the exception your receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try an alternative method.  Especially if you see what RunCommandAsync is expected to do with the BsonDocument.  See  [Unit test for RunCommandAsync](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/dd085df754ce87863b38836427a8836ada4cfc9b/src/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/MongoDatabaseImplTests.cs)

Assuming you are using mongodb 3.0, can you consider the code below an alternative?

```
    using (var results = await context.Users.Indexes.ListAsync())
    {
        while (await results.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            foreach (var current in results.Current)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(current["name"].AsString);
            }
        }
    }
```