# MongoDB c# driver RunCommandAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb

I would like to run `db.printReplicationInfo()` from the c# driver.

As far as I can tell, I can only run the commands listed [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/) using `MongoDatabase.RunCommandAsync`.  To do that, I have code that looks like this:

```
var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument
{
    {"replSetGetStatus", 1}
});
var result = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<ReplicaSetStatus>(
             client.GetDatabase(ADMIN_DATABASE).RunCommandAsync(command).Result);
```

This lets me run the command and deserialize the response into a `ReplicaSetStatus` object that we've created. (client is an instance of MongoClient).

My question is can I use `RunCommandAsync` to perform an operation like `db.printReplicationInfo()`?  What would the command look like?

If not, what is the best way to run an operation like that from c#?

Looks like someone else had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393329/c-sharp-mongo-runcommandasync), but didn't get any helpful answers.

Thanks!

Comment: NOTE
The db.printReplicationInfo() in the mongo shell does not return JSON. Use db.printReplicationInfo() for manual inspection, and db.getReplicationInfo() in scripts.
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.printReplicationInfo/

Comment: I ended up giving up on the C# driver and doing it in javascript instead.

Answer (score 0):

db.printReplicationInfo() and db.GetReplicationInfo() are MongoDb shell functions that you can't use outide the shell.

You can see the functions yourself in the mongo shell:

```
rs:PRIMARY> db.getReplicationInfo

function() {
    var localdb = this.getSiblingDB("local");

    var result = {};
    var oplog;
    var localCollections = localdb.getCollectionNames();
    if (localCollections.indexOf('oplog.rs') >= 0) {
        oplog = 'oplog.rs';
    } else {
        result.errmsg = "replication not detected";
        return result;
    }

    var ol = localdb.getCollection(oplog);
    var ol_stats = ol.stats();
    if (ol_stats && ol_stats.maxSize) {
        result.logSizeMB = ol_stats.maxSize / (1024 * 1024);
    } else {
        result.errmsg = "Could not get stats for local." + oplog + " collection. " +
            "collstats returned: " + tojson(ol_stats);
        return result;
    }

    result.usedMB = ol_stats.size / (1024 * 1024);
    result.usedMB = Math.ceil(result.usedMB * 100) / 100;

    var firstc = ol.find().sort({$natural: 1}).limit(1);
    var lastc = ol.find().sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1);
    if (!firstc.hasNext() || !lastc.hasNext()) {
        result.errmsg =
            "objects not found in local.oplog.$main -- is this a new and empty db instance?";
        result.oplogMainRowCount = ol.count();
        return result;
    }

    var first = firstc.next();
    var last = lastc.next();
    var tfirst = first.ts;
    var tlast = last.ts;

    if (tfirst && tlast) {
        tfirst = DB.tsToSeconds(tfirst);
        tlast = DB.tsToSeconds(tlast);
        result.timeDiff = tlast - tfirst;
        result.timeDiffHours = Math.round(result.timeDiff / 36) / 100;
        result.tFirst = (new Date(tfirst * 1000)).toString();
        result.tLast = (new Date(tlast * 1000)).toString();
        result.now = Date();
    } else {
        result.errmsg = "ts element not found in oplog objects";
    }

    return result;
}

rs:PRIMARY> db.printReplicationInfo

function() {
    var result = this.getReplicationInfo();
    if (result.errmsg) {
        var isMaster = this.isMaster();
        if (isMaster.arbiterOnly) {
            print("cannot provide replication status from an arbiter.");
            return;
        } else if (!isMaster.ismaster) {
            print("this is a slave, printing slave replication info.");
            this.printSlaveReplicationInfo();
            return;
        }
        print(tojson(result));
        return;
    }
    print("configured oplog size:   " + result.logSizeMB + "MB");
    print("log length start to end: " + result.timeDiff + "secs (" + result.timeDiffHours + "hrs)");
    print("oplog first event time:  " + result.tFirst);
    print("oplog last event time:   " + result.tLast);
    print("now:                     " + result.now);
}
```